# How to serialize a File and another object

Tags: java, serialization, jms

I am interested in trying to serialize a file's contents - as in, the actual bytes, which I have a handle on with a java File object.
I see that File is serializable, but it is just for the Path.

I have another JMS object that I want to associate with the File - so I was thinking of making a Parent object that contains the File contents and the other object. Serialize that parent object.

There are a few problems as I see.

1) My files could be anywhere from 1Kb to 10GB. How can you handle large files? 
2) Serializing might be slow on larger files?

My plan was to put this serialized object with the  JMS and File bytes into a database. Would I be better off just trying to put the file in directly, and only serializing the JMS message? It wont be quite as neat, but maybe necessary?

Also, I am using Camel as my broker. I know it has some serialization features, and in fact the first example in the docs for it is for creating a blob from a binary file. It also says it uses plain Java serializer, so I dont know if that helps or hurts that I'm using Camel.

Comment: It seems that you want to serialize the file's content (which is not the same as serializing the file itself). If that is the case, please update your title and question. Don't forget that a file can be written by other programs than yours...

Comment: the first line says the actual bytes of the file, but I can try to make it clearer

Comment: A file is a bunch of bytes, I can't imagine what you think you want to serialize that further down too. You need to expand your question with the problem you are actually trying to solve, because I can't imagine a design that includes 'serializing' around 10GB files is going to survive the light of day.

Comment: The reason for serializing is because I am trying to create a "package" that contains the message carrying all this metadata in the form of the JMS message, with the actual bytes of the file.

Comment: Still not clear what you are trying to do. "serialize" normally means "turn an Object into a bunch of bytes" but a file is already a bunch of bytes. Do you mean you need to load bytes from a file and send them over JMS? That isn't [serialisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization).

Answer (score 0):

The serialization of a huge amount of data is probably considered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129695/java-serializing-a-huge-amount-of-data-to-a-single-file/129734), but if your aim is to turn a bunch of bytes of a file into another bunch of bytes, I think, something may be wrong with the idea itself.

Comment: No it isn't. That's how to serialize *to* a file.

Comment: You are right, I edited the answer. At first I looked at the "huge amount of data" part, but this question is more interesting and strange due to the turning a bunch of bytes of a file into a bunch of bytes (as a serialized object).