# Vertx 3 - Java serializing large objects

Tags: java, serialization, vert.x, jackson2

Vertx 3 Newbie. I'm using the Java API. The usecase is for a reporting app which typically deals with large objects (POJOs). These POJOs contain the data to be exported into PDF, CSV etc and these are typically List of Maps.
I'm wondering if I have to asynchronously pass around the data to different verticles via the EventBus, there is going to be a cost of serialization/deserialization. Are there any tips/tricks while dealing with large objects so that we don't incur a huge overhead for serialization/deserialization?

Comment: What could be the size?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129695/java-serializing-a-huge-amount-of-data-to-a-single-file

Comment: ranging from 50MB to 100MB

Answer (score 1):

I think it's bad idea to send anything large through EventBus. You may use vertx SharedData, and send only id of your object.

```java
   LocalMap<String, LargeObject> map = vertx.sharedData.getLocalMap("uniq-map-id");
   map.put("unique-id", data);
   vertx.eventBus.send(ADDRESS, "unique-id");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy anonymous worker verticle to do that:

Assuming LongOperatingVerticle is the verticle that handles your POJO's:

```
class LongOperatingVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

    @Override
    public void start() {

        final String pojo = "Very long file...";


        final Future<String> f = Future.future();

        // Anonymous verticle in worker mode
        this.vertx.deployVerticle(new AbstractVerticle() {
            @Override
            public void start() throws Exception {

                Thread.sleep(5000);
                f.complete("Ok");
            }
        }, new DeploymentOptions().setWorker(true));

        System.out.println("Will wait now");

        f.setHandler((e) -> {
            System.out.println(e.result());
        });

    }
}
```